# (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE) returns null

Tags: android, service, locationmanager

I have a service and in its onCreate()-method I try to get an instance of the LocationManager class.

```
 LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

In my activity I create a new intent und start the service.

```
 Intent t = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class);
               MainActivity.this.startService(t);
```

It works fine as long I register the service in the manifest this way:

```
 <service
        android:name="de.path.MyService" />
```

The point is that I want to run the service in its own process, so I added to the service declaration:

```
 android:process=":MyGPSProcess"
```

Starting the service now I get a NullPointerException telling me that the ILocationManager mService in LocationManager is null.

Is there no context availiable? Is there a way to get a SystemService?

Comment: Declare this----> private LocationManager locationMangaer = null;

Comment: didn't work. Still get the same error